# Why do I keep getting a 'System.OutOfMemoryException'?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

Here is my Code, I am trying to stitch two pictures together and as soon as I get to line 42 "Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);" I get an out of memory error. What should I do?

```
namespace Practicing_Stiching
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdCombine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Change the path to location where your images are stored.
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Elder Zollinger\Desktop\Images");
            if (directory != null)
            {
                FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
                CombineImages(files);
            }

        }
        private void CombineImages(FileInfo[] files)
        {
            //change the location to store the final image.
            string finalImage = @"C:\Users\Elder Zollinger\Desktop\Images";
            List<int> imageHeights = new List<int>();
            int nIndex = 0;
            int width = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                width += img.Width;
                img.Dispose();
            }
            imageHeights.Sort();
            int height = imageHeights[imageHeights.Count - 1];
            Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
            g.Clear(SystemColors.AppWorkspace);
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                if (nIndex == 0)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
                    nIndex++;
                    width = img.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawImage(img, new Point(width, 0));
                    width += img.Width;
                }
                img.Dispose();
            }
            g.Dispose();
            img3.Save(finalImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            img3.Dispose();
            imageLocation.Image = Image.FromFile(finalImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend wrapping all of your use of `IDisposable` items in a `using` clause.  How large is the resulting image going to be?

Comment: I think a more appropriate question is how large are all the initial images?  That is where this is bombing.  You have too many images open at once (or something to that effect).  Using the current code, you'd have to get more RAM.  Otherwise, better techniques may help.  Also, please tell us what version of .NET and the OS (plus 32x or 64x in the case of windows server 2003).

Comment: Only two images?  Are there any non-images in that folder?  Hidden files?  Maybe you should filter to `.jpg`.

Comment: There are just 2 jpeg files in the folder

Comment: Also: Are you sure about the new file's name you want to save?

Comment: You can eliminate that `imageHeights` collection by simply updating a `highestHeight` variable, if the current image height is larger than the `highestHeight`.

Comment: Are you sure you've got hidden files displayed? It might be `thumbs.db` or something like that :)

Comment: +1 for thinking of thumbs.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get more memory!

But seriously, you don't appear to be filtering out files that are not image files. There are some hidden files in folders that you may be trying to open as an image accidentally, such as "Thumbs.db". Make sure that the file is an image with something like `if (Path.GetExtension(file.FullPath) != ".png") continue;`.

Also, on objects that you are calling `.Dispose()` on, consider wrapping them in a `using()` instead. For example:

```
using(var img = Image.FromFile(file.FullPath))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked really well. I did have another file in the folder.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the solution if it resolved your problem! Good luck.

Comment: just one more quick question, not fully resolved, it wont let me use FullPath and says Error 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FullPath' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: To be honest, I never use FileInfo or DirectoryInfo. Try using `Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.png")` which will just give you strings, and `Path.GetFullPath(p)`. I pretty much always use the static Directory, File and Path classes.

Answer (score 4):

That's likely GDI playing tricks on you.

You see, when GDI encounters an unknown file, it will quite likely cause an `OutOfMemoryException`. Since you're not filtering the input images at all, I'd expect that you're simply grabbing a non-image file (or an image type that GDI doesn't understand).

Oh, and a bit sideways - make sure you set JPEG quality when saving JPEGs - the default is something like 75, which is rather bad for a lot of images. And please, do use `using` - it's very handy to ensure proper and timely clean-up :)